# Two-bit branch prediction should give higher percentage

Tags: branch-prediction

I have small program that is supposed to calculate percentage of successfull predicition of a 2-bit branch predictor. I have it all done but my output isn't what I have expected, the percantage stops at about 91% instead of what I think should be at 98% or 99%. I think the problem might be with how apply the mask to the address. Can some one look at my code and verify if that is the issue.

The program iterates through a file that has a branch history of a run of the gcc compiler consisting of about 1792 addresses and a single digit column with 1 for a branch taken and a 0 for a branch not taken.

```
static void twoBitPredictor_v1(StreamWriter sw)
    {
        uint hxZero = 0x000000000;
        uint uMask1 = 0x00000000;
        int nCorrectPrediction = 0;
        uint uSize2;
        int nSize;
        int nTotalReads;
        int nTableMin = 2;
        int nTableMax = 16;
        int nTaken = 0;
        uint[] uArrBt1;

        sw.WriteLine("\n\nTwo-Bit Predictor Results Ver. 1\n");
        sw.WriteLine("-------------------------\n");
        sw.WriteLine("Total" + "\t" + "Correct");
        sw.WriteLine("Reads" + "\t" + "Prediction" + "\t" + "Percentage");
        System.Console.WriteLine("\n\nTwo-Bit Predictor Results Ver. 1\n");
        System.Console.WriteLine("-------------------------\n");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Total" + "\t" + "Correct");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Reads" + "\t" + "Prediction" + "\t" + "Percentage");

        for (int _i = nTableMin; _i <= nTableMax; _i++)
        {
            StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\gccHist.txt");
            nSize = _i;
            uSize2 = (uint)(Math.Pow(2, nSize));
            uArrBt1 = new uint[2 * uSize2];

            for (int i = 0; i < uSize2; i++)
                uArrBt1[i] = hxZero;

            nCorrectPrediction = 0;
            nTotalReads = 0;

            while (!sr2.EndOfStream)
            {
                String[] strLineRead = sr2.ReadLine().Split(',');
                uint uBRAddress = Convert.ToUInt32(strLineRead[0], 16);
                uint bBranchTaken = Convert.ToUInt32(strLineRead[2]);

   >>>>>   In the line below is where I think lies the problem but not sure how to correct it.
                uMask1 = uBRAddress & (0xffffffff >> 32 - nSize);
                int _mask = Convert.ToInt32(uMask1);
                nTaken = Convert.ToInt32(uArrBt1[2 * _mask]);

                switch (Convert.ToInt32(uArrBt1[_mask]))
                {
                    case 0:

                        if (bBranchTaken == 0) // Branch Not Taken
                            nCorrectPrediction++;
                        else
                            uArrBt1[_mask] = 1;

                        break;

                    case 1:

                        if (bBranchTaken == 0)
                        {
                            uArrBt1[_mask] = 0;
                            nCorrectPrediction++;
                        }
                        else
                            uArrBt1[_mask] = 3;

                        break;

                    case 2:

                        if (bBranchTaken == 0)
                        {
                            uArrBt1[_mask] = 3;
                            nCorrectPrediction++;
                        }
                        else
                            uArrBt1[_mask] = 0;

                        break;

                    case 3:

                        if (bBranchTaken == 0)
                            uArrBt1[_mask] = 2;
                        else                                
                            nCorrectPrediction++;

                        break;                    
                }
                nTotalReads++;
            }
            sr2.Close();
            double percentage = ((double)nCorrectPrediction / (double)nTotalReads) * 100;
            sw.WriteLine(nTotalReads + "\t" + nCorrectPrediction + "\t\t" + Math.Round(percentage, 2) + "%");
            System.Console.WriteLine(nTotalReads + "\t" + nCorrectPrediction + "\t\t" + Math.Round(percentage, 2) + "%");
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Two-Bit Predictor Results Ver. 1
-------------------------

Total   Correct
Reads   Prediction      Percentage
1792    997             55.64%
1792    997             55.64%
1792    1520            84.82%
1792    1522            84.93%
1792    1521            84.88%
1792    1639            91.46%
1792    1651            92.13%
1792    1649            92.02%
1792    1649            92.02%
1792    1648            91.96%
1792    1646            91.85%
1792    1646            91.85%
1792    1646            91.85%
1792    1646            91.85%
1792    1646            91.85%
```